# jqgrid question

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Do you consider jqgrid being a good solution since you cannot set its width in percent and only in pixels?
Are there any alternatives?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to work around this. For example, you could put the grid inside a DIV that is set to 60% width (for example), and use the jqGrid autowidth option.

Alternatively you can always call setGridWidth() to change a grid's width dynamically - you could use this to simulate a percentage if you bind to a resize event and write some jQuery to calculate the proper width. Probably more code than you wanted to write, but not too much.

So far I have been very happy using jqGrid. It has an excellent set of features, is being actively developed/improved, and the theme support is great - especially if you already use jQuery UI Themes.

Answer (score 1):

jQgrid is best grid plugin for jQuery it's well documented: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs. I is also supported in asp.net MVC framework with component. Demo at: http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx. Did i mentioned that MS supports jQuery :)

Yesterday Tony added new metod to jQgrid: gridResize, which can resize the grid. Also use a jQuery UI resizable and can use any options of this widget. The method should be refined

More at:
http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/a008ebf7b8ad684b21e51f21eed4301b82bc66f2